# use older version of jar to override newer system libs

Tags: java, android

My android app needs to use some methods in commons-httpclient-3.1 that are not available in newer versions of commons-httpclient. I can bundle the jar of commons-httpclient-3.1 with my app, but the problem is, Android *comes with its own* version of commons-httpclient and that seems to override whatever i included. For one, Eclipse wouldnt even let me build the project.

Any simple workarounds, besides downloading the source for commons-httpclient-3.1 and refactoring it into a different package??

Thx

Comment: I'm curious as to what capabilities were removed from the old `HttpClient` line that are not in the new `HttpComponents` line. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Java Build Bath -> Order and Export tab -> put your library higher than android lib.
This should help

Comment: Note that this is probably only going to help within your Eclipse workspace. Your actual build/install process is going to have to take care of the classpath issues in the finished build.